removeObserver() does not remove the observer (android, java)
I have a viewModel and an observer that works perfectly good. Actually, too good because the observer refuses to be removed even when I ask nicely.
Can anyone see what is wrong?
This is what I have tried:
  MyViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
  final Observer<List<String>> my_observer = new Observer<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<String> firstNames) {
                ... some code ...
            }
        };

  viewModel.getFirstNames(lastName).observe(this,my_observer);
  viewModel.getFirstNames(lastName).removeObserver(my_observer);

I have also tried removeObservers(this,my_observer), but the code inside my_observer is run whenever one of the "firstNames" are changed, added or deleted (and "lastName" is kept unchanged).
There are lots of issues on this all over stackoverflow, and I have spend hours (maybe even days) reading, searching and trying, but none of the questions and answers I have found, solve my issue as the others lack the input to the viewModel (here "lastName").
Here is more of the code as requested - it works well as I do get all the first names. ;-)
--- MyViewModel ---
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    public static MyRepository myRepository;

    public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        myRepository = new MyRepository(application);
    }

    public LiveData<List<String>> getFirstNames(String lastName){
        return myRepository.getFirstNames(lastName);
    }
}

--- MyRepository ---
public class MyRepository {
    private final MyDao myDao;

    public MyRepository(Application application) {
        MyRoomDatabase db = MyRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        myDao = db.myDao();
    }

    public LiveData<List<String>> getFirstNames(String lastName){
        return myDao.getFirstNames(lastName);
    }
}

--- MyDao ---
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_names AS tn " +
            "WHERE tn.lastname LIKE :lastName " +
            "ORDER BY tn.firstname ASC")
    LiveData<List<String>> getFirstNames(String lastName);
}


Please include the code for getFirstNames(lastName) (and what would be really helpful is ~all of the code in that ViewModel on how your data flow works).

@ianhanniballake, I have now added more of the code. I did not do it at first, because that part works. The observer is giving me all the first names, but it does not stop when I try to remove the observer.

Your getFirstNames shouldn't be returning a new LiveData in the first place - instead, you need a single LiveData instance stored in your ViewModel - besides always returning the same instance every time you call your method, it will also ensure that your data is saved and restored when you return to this same fragment - something keeping the LiveData instance in the Fragment won't necessarily help with. Note that while the duplicate question uses the liveData {} block, that wouldn't be necessary in your case.

It's a funny thing that often happens when you finally ask for help: You tend to figure it out yourself...
I had initialized my observer but not my LiveData instance. Therefore, I created an anonymous LiveData instance that could not be removed.
This is what finally worked for me:
MyViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

// Store the LiveData instance in a variable
LiveData<List<String>> liveNames = viewModel.getFirstNames(lastName);

// Observe the LiveData
liveName.observe(this, names -> {
     ... some code ...
     // Remove all observers for the liveData instance
     liveNames.removeObservers(this);
});

Hope it helps someone ;-)
